# Behaviour of Brownian motion for large times

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, brownian-motion

I know that for a one dimensional Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ it holds that
$$P(\liminf_{t\rightarrow \infty} B_t = -\infty)=P(\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty} B_t = \infty)=1.$$

How does this translate to $d$-dimensional Brownian motion? What would be the analogous statement? $P(\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} |B_t| = \infty)=1$ would not be correct I guess because this is precisely the definition of transience which does only hold for $d\geq 3$.

I am asking because I often read that the upper statement is used to argue that a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion leaves any ball around $0$ with probability $1$ and I don't know how to conclude this from the one dimensional case.

Can somebody explain?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't this follow immediately from the fact that each component of $d$-dimensional Brownian motion is a one-dimensional Brownian motion, and the fact that the event that a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion escapes a ball of radius $r$ is implied by any one of the coordinates exceeding $r$ in magnitude?

Comment: @JasonGaitonde Yes, but wouldn't this imply $P(\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} |B_t| = \infty) =1$ (which is only true for $d \geq 3$)?

Comment: No, it would imply $\Pr(\lim\sup_{t\to \infty} \vert B_t\vert=\infty)=1$. This is a much weaker statement.

Comment: True. Thanks a lot.